# How does one close an Akka stream?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am updating some experimental spray code to akka-stream (2.0.2), so I'm going through he documentation little by little. One of the needs I have is that if I detect a protocol violation in my stream, I need to close the stream immediately and kick off the client.

What is the proper way of immediately closing (terminating) the stream from inside a Flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `PushStage`:

```
import akka.stream.stage._

val closeStage = new PushStage[Tpe, Tpe] {
  override def onPush(elem: Tpe, ctx: Context[Tpe]) = elem match {
    case elem if shouldCloseStream ⇒
      // println("stream closed")
      ctx.finish()
    case elem ⇒
      ctx.push(elem)
  }
}
```

You can combine a `PushStage` with a `Flow` through the `transform` method:

```
Flow[Tpe]
.map(...)
.transform(() ⇒ closeStage)
.map(...)
```

Comment: In case you are still reading this, I just noticed that in 2.4.2 PushStage is deprecated. How would you accomplish this inside a GraphStage? I tried completeStage, but that's not it.

Comment: I added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544856/closing-an-akka-stream-2-4-2