# Closing an Akka stream from inside a GraphStage (Akka 2.4.2)

Tags: scala, akka-stream

In Akka Stream 2.4.2, PushStage has been deprecated. For Streams 2.0.3 I was using the solution from this answer:

[How does one close an Akka stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954144/how-does-one-close-an-akka-stream)

which was:

```
import akka.stream.stage._

    val closeStage = new PushStage[Tpe, Tpe] {
      override def onPush(elem: Tpe, ctx: Context[Tpe]) = elem match {
        case elem if shouldCloseStream ⇒
          // println("stream closed")
          ctx.finish()
        case elem ⇒
          ctx.push(elem)
      }
    }
```

How would I close a stream in 2.4.2 immediately, from inside a GraphStage / onPush() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
val closeStage = new GraphStage[FlowShape[Tpe, Tpe]] {
  val in = Inlet[Tpe]("closeStage.in")
  val out = Outlet[Tpe]("closeStage.out")

  override val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    setHandler(in, new InHandler {
      override def onPush() = grab(in) match {
        case elem if shouldCloseStream ⇒
          // println("stream closed")
          completeStage()
        case msg ⇒
          push(out, msg)
      }
    })
    setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
      override def onPull() = pull(in)
    })
  }
}
```

It is more verbose but one the one side one can define this logic in a reusable way and on the other side one no longer has to worry about differences between the stream elements because the `GraphStage` can be handled in the same way as a flow would be handled:

```
val flow: Flow[Tpe] = ???
val newFlow = flow.via(closeStage)
```

Comment: That's what I originally tried, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. After I do a completeStage() and I close the client, a minute later I get an exception on my server, "Aborting TCP connection because of upstream failure: No elements pased in the last 1 minute."  http://pastebin.com/utu11L2h

Comment: Sure, `completeStage` only closes the stream on the client, not the one on the server. Before calling `completeStage` you can send the server a message that you are going to shutdown the client and that it can close the connection.

Comment: I think that's what I'm missing then, I'm not seeing the big picture, sorry if this sounds stupid. When you say "send the server a message", how would that work?  It cannot be anything coming from the client saying "I'm leaving", since I'm closing the connection because the client is misbehaving (locked up, lagged, bad implementation, protocol violation, etc) and may not send an "I'm leaving". The Close needs to be server driven from a GraphStage.

Comment: Well, if you lost connection to the server, then there is nothing you can do on the client side. What is the problem with the failure on the server? The client is gone and the failure tells you so.

Comment: I think my problem is a) I don't like unhandled exceptions or exceptions in general, and b) there are still resources used for 1 minute. But the point is, the client is not gone, I want to kick it off whether it wants to cooperate or not. A lagging or hung client for example could still have a connection, just not be able to send or receive data.

Comment: exceptions in streams are not unhandled. The resource usage probably is also not very severe. If you really can't come up with an idea about what to do when the client doesn't respond anymore, you should ask a new question. Maybe even on the mailing lists or somewhere else because such questions usually are not a good fit for SO.

Comment: Well, my fault for embellishing the question too much in comments. All I want to do is kick off the client immediately and close connection, freeing resources. Reason doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Posting for other people's reference. sschaef's answer is correct procedurally, but the connections was kept open for a minute and eventually would time out and throw a "no activity" exception, closing the connection.

In reading the docs further, I noticed that the connection was closed when all upstreams flows completed. In my case, I had more than one upstream.

For my particular use case, the fix was to add eagerComplete=true to close stream as soon as any (rather than all) upstream completes. Something like:

```
... = builder.add(Merge[MyObj](3,eagerComplete = true))
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'd also recommend marking the answer by @sschaef as correct as it answers the question, and since might help people (like me) who have the 'how to close a flow' problem without the 'eagerComplete' problem